# Javascript Math Round

Tags: javascript, jquery

im getting a little issue here. Im trying to do a simple math, but im forgetting something.

Here's what:

```
var valorOriginal = 9.90;

var discount = Math.round(valorOriginal*12*0.25);
var anual = Math.round(valorOriginal*12)-discount;

alert(anual);
```

If you do this math on calc, it will give you `89.1`, but im just getting 89 rounded. Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you still need to finish translating some of that code?

Comment: is desconto a misspelling for discount? or is it another variable defined elsewhere?

Comment: Why do you round() if you don't want to round?

Comment: Why does it surprise you that you're getting 89 instead of 89.1? As @Jani points out in his answer, that's exactly what `Math.round` is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Math.round rounds up to the nearest integer value. So you will loose the decimal points. If you want the decimal, you are probably after toFixed().

```
var valorOriginal = 9.90;

var discount = (valorOriginal*12*0.25);
var anual = (valorOriginal*12)-discount;

alert( anual.toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: Note that toFixed returns a string. In some scenarios this could lead to unexpected results. If used in a calculation, prefix the result with a + to force a conversion to a number. eg: _var anualAsNumer = +anual.toFixed(2);_

Answer (score 6):

That's exactly what Round method will do for you.

Rounding the number to closest integer.

Answer (score 2):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5jDP8/)

You need to add this method:

```
Math.roundMoney = function(number) {
    return Math.round(number * 100) / 100;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
var valorOriginal = 9.90;

var discount = Math.roundMoney(valorOriginal*12*0.25);
var anual = Math.roundMoney(valorOriginal*12)-discount;

alert(anual);
```

Comment: Up vote for showing how `Math` object can be extended with new method. I'm not familiar with this technique. Is this because of prototypes? (The next JavaScript feature I want to study.) Can you add a couple of comments? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

anual is a variable obtained by a difference between two rounded values, so the result should be rounded too

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript Math.round function will round on 0 decimals and your calculator will round on 2 decimals.

So you need to make a little trick:

```
Math.nativeRound = Math.round;
Math.round = function(i, iDecimals) {
    if (!iDecimals)
        return Math.nativeRound(i);
    else
       return Math.nativeRound(i * Math.pow(10, Math.abs(iDecimals))) / Math.pow(10, Math.abs(iDecimals));

};

var valorOriginal = 9.90;

var discount = Math.round(valorOriginal*12*0.25, 2);
var anual = Math.round(valorOriginal*12, 2)-discount;

alert(anual);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/p34EC/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `toFixed` method which preserving ( rounding to ) a count of decimal numbers passed in arguments and you can also shorten this operation to:

```
var valorOriginal = 9.90;
( ( valorOriginal - valorOriginal / 10 ) * 10 ).toFixed(2) //"89.10"
```

Comment: Sorry, `10` instead `100` - By the rush don't checked.
Now is correct.